# Can I switch from a Community to Portal without logging in again

Tags: single-sign-on, authentication, force.com-sites, portal, community

I have an existing force.com authenticated site and i am building a community at the moment. I have enabled a profile for both the authenticated site and the community. I can login to both of these separately with the same user.
In the community, I have a link to the authenticated site but when the link opens - I am asked to login again even though the user has access to both the community and the authenticated site.

Does anyone know a way to prevent the user from having to login a second time when moving from the community to the authenticated site?